# How do I upgrade to Google's Universal Analytics using the Google Analytics module?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site using version 1.4 of the Google Analytics module and I wanted to upgrade to Universal Analytics.  The module page says that I need the 2.x version of the module, so I updated to 2.x-dev, ran update.php (no updates necessary), and cleared the cache.

I then logged into Google Analytics and went to **Audience -> Demographics -> Overview**, after which I clicked **Validate tracking code**, but this failed.

So, I went to the module's config page (*admin/config/system/googleanalytics*) and checked **Track display features** under **Search and advertising**.  I then cleared the cache.

I again tried to re-validate but it continues to ask me to validate.

What more do I need to do to upgrade to Universal Analytics?

Comment: Worth mentioning I did a write on this (especially if you have custom GA tracking code) on my blog http://www.pixelite.co.nz/article/updating-drupal-use-google-analytics-universal-tracking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to 2.0, cleared the cache several times, and then waited about an hour-- now it works!  So I guess sometimes you just have to wait a bit after upgrading.